# Is there an OpenSource alternative for AWS?

Tags: open-source, amazon

AWS is phenomenal in the services and server stack it provides. I am not looking for a full scale but atleast some feature OpenSource solution similar to it. Is there one?

As requested adding a list of services and server expectations from my basic knowledge:

1. Domain name
2. Hosting
3. Cloud IDE
4. DCVS
5. A Development Pipeline to commit, build and deploy
6. Application server
7. Storage
8. Load Balancing
9. Auto scaling
10. It should allow SSH and this SFPT so incase either of this is on a third party an integration can be established.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: AWS started as a simple queue service, only that service was available. Then they added remote storage. There are open source alternatives for both, some predating AWS. AWS keeps adding new services, for which there are almost always open source equivalents. The point of my comment is: If you don't tell us exactly what services you need, then we can not help you. Please edit your question and list all services you need, then ask us to reopen, thanks!

Comment: Welcome aboard. I have to agree that the question is far to broad. please read [ask], then give us a list of requirements. The more detail that you can give, the more that we can help you - and we ***want*** to help you :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Please see the edit details and let me know if these will suffice for a more better understanding.

Comment: @Mawg Looking for the promised help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for OpenStack? https://www.openstack.org/

> OpenStack is a free and open-source software platform for cloud
>   computing, mostly deployed as infrastructure-as-a-service, whereby
>   virtual servers and other resources are made available to customers.

Comment: very interesting. The question is AWS provides a free T2 Micro instance for a year. I can build adn run a whole stack on it, without ofcourse load balancing, auto scaling etc. All FREE of cost. I am working on Webapp so I can actuallu purchase a Domain, Use  Hosting Server, Use a DevOps environment and ofcourse deploy all using AWS. So as far as OpenStack is concerned it seems to do a great job, post deployment. Is it free? More importantly What about the services before deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GlusterFS: https://www.gluster.org/

GlusterFS is a distributed file system that presents storage elements from multiple servers as a unified file system.

We have it in use and are thrilled!

Comment: I have the same query for you, The question is AWS provides a free T2 Micro instance for a year. I can build adn run a whole stack on it, without ofcourse load balancing, auto scaling etc. All FREE of cost. I am working on Webapp so I can actuallu purchase a Domain, Use  Hosting Server, Use a DevOps environment and ofcourse deploy all using AWS. So as far as Gluster is concerned it seems to do a great job, post deployment. Is it free? More importantly What about the services before deployment?